# Resize and positioning images for android that works on all devices

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout, resize

Fixed post.

So i have this two image wherein i want to make it centered and the next one centered again so it will be properly aligned when i load it on other device. it works perfectly fine  But i know that the size varies depending on the density and such. I cant seem to properly align my backgrounds on the middle because of different phone screen sizes. so whats the best approach that i should do?

first background is for design, the box one.
the darker one is gonna be the default wherein ill replace with the picture that i took from the camera.

desired result which works on my phone size:
http://puu.sh/4XcuZ.jpg.

problem picture:
http://puu.sh/4Xcsk.jpg

Any idea how can i make them fit so they will properly work on any devices? My UI is so messed up because i am trying to fit them accordingly. ive read that i should use Dp,fill_parent and such but it's kinda confusing. any tips? Like the first thing that i wanna accomplish is to make my firstbackground have an even size when loaded to any device, then secondbackground.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@drawable/test"
     android:padding="10dp">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     >

        <ImageView

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/firstbackground" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     >



    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="336dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"

     >
  <ImageView
        android:@+id/ivReturnImage
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/secondbackground" />



    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"

    >    

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibTakePic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:background="@drawable/take_picture" />


        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibRotateImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:background="@drawable/object_rotate_left" />

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibOpenImage"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:background="@drawable/picture_book" />

             <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/bSetWallpaper"
           android:layout_width="40dp"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:background="@drawable/preferences_desktop_wallpaper"/>



                   <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/bSaveImage"
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="45dp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:padding="10dp"
           android:background="@drawable/document_save"/>

</LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>

 <SlidingDrawer
     android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
     android:layout_width="273dp"
     android:layout_height="550dp"
     android:content="@+id/content"
     android:handle="@+id/handle"
     android:topOffset="390dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/handle"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="48dp" >

         <ImageView
             android:layout_width="180dp"
             android:layout_height="33dp"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             android:src="@drawable/handle" />
     </RelativeLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/drawer_background"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Please select a filter" />

     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/spinner1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="41dp" />

         <Spinner
             android:id="@+id/spinner2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="41dp" />

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:padding="10dp" >

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/bImplement"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Implement Effect" />

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/bOriginal"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Revert to original" />
         </LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>
     </SlidingDrawer>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
see if u want to go with layout format that you have to make some drawable like 
1.drawable-hdpi
2.drawable-large
3.drawable-ldpi
4.drawable-xhdpi
5.drawable-xlarge-mdpi
6.drawable-xxhdpi

and make all layout respectively then your app is going fine on any mobile tablet blue stack AOC android device 

if u go with java code then 
    int density= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

    if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH)
                            System.out.println("Density is high");

                        if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH)
                            System.out.println("Density is xxhigh");

                        if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH)
                            System.out.println("Density is xxxhigh");

                        if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV)
                            System.out.println("Density is Tv"); 

if(widthDp==600)
                    {
                        imageWidth =  ;
                        imgHeight =  ;
                        margin =  ;
                    }
                    else if (widthDp==720)
                    {

                    }
                    else if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH)
                    {
                        imageWidth =  ;
                        imgHeight =  ;
                        margin =  ;
                    }
                    else if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW)
                    {
                        imageWidth =  ;
                        imgHeight =  ;
                        margin =  ;
                    }
                    else if(density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM)
                    {
                        imageWidth =  ;
                        imgHeight =  ;
                        margin =  ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imageWidth =  ;
                        imgHeight =  ;
                        margin =  ;
                    }

do what ever way u like :)
BEST OF LUCK DUDE :)
```